# Terminal in Mac Book Air not found

Tags: mac, terminal

I have to open the terminal from latest version of Mac Book Air(13 inch). In the utilities, there is no terminal emulator found. On pressing shift+Command+U, nothing is found. Is there another namesake for terminal. Command Prompt also is not to be found. Is it shell script by any chance. Note that Utilities was found in Automator in Applications Tab. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal can be found by using spotlight search. We press "Command+space" and then type terminal in the search bar. Now, the terminal opens and can be used instantly.